# Keras/TF: Time Distributed CNN+LSTM for visual recognition

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

[image]

I am trying to implement the Model from the article (https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.4389) that basically consists of time-distributed CNNs followed by a sequence of LSTMs using Keras with TF.

However, I am having a problem trying to figure out if I should include the `TimeDirstibuted` function just for my Convolutional & Pooling Layers or also for the LSTMs?

Is there a way to run the CNN Layers in parallel (Based on the number of frames in the sequence that I want to process and based on the number of cores that I have)?

And Last, suppose that each entry is composed of "n" frames (in sequence) where n varies based on the current data entry, what is the best suitable input dimension? and would "n" be the batch size? Is there a way to limit the number of CNNs in // to for example 4 (so that you get an output Y after 4 frames are processed)?

P.S.: The inputs are small videos (i.e. a sequence of frames)

P.S.: The output dimension is irrelevant to my question, so it is not discussed here

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

[Edited]
Sorry, only-a-link-answer was bad. So I try to answer question one by one.

> if I should include the TimeDirstibuted function just for my Convolutional & Pooling Layers or also for the LSTMs?

Use TimeDistributed function only for Conv and Pooling layers, no need for LSTMs.

> Is there a way to run the CNN Layers in parallel?

No, if you use CPU. It's possible if you utilize GPU.
[Transparent Multi-GPU Training on TensorFlow with Keras](https://medium.com/@kuza55/transparent-multi-gpu-training-on-tensorflow-with-keras-8b0016fd9012)

> what is the best suitable input dimension?

Five. (batch, time, width, height, channel).

> Is there a way to limit the number of CNNs in // to for example 4

You can do this in the preprocess by manually aligning frames into a specific number, not in the network. In other words, "time" dimension should be 4 if you want to have output after 4 frames are processed.

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(
    TimeDistributed(
        Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'), 
        input_shape=(data.num_frames, data.width, data.height, 1)
    )
)
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(1, 1))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(128, (4,4), activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(256, (4,4), activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))))

# extract features and dropout 
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

# input to LSTM
model.add(LSTM(256, return_sequences=False, dropout=0.5))

# classifier with sigmoid activation for multilabel
model.add(Dense(data.num_classes, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Reference:
[PRI-MATRIX FACTORIZATION - BENCHMARK](http://drivendata.co/blog/pri-matrix-factorization-benchmark/)

Comment: I receive the following error: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected seq_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (64, 224, 224, 3) how the reshape input from the train_datagen.flow_from_directory?

Comment: softmax instead of sigmoid if num_classes>1